Not able to Inject from Java code into Kotlin Dependency Components
Using the latest version for Dagger 2,
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.51.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.51.1'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.51.1"

I am no able to inject the objects from activity using Dagger 2, dependency injection components and modules have been written in Kotlin.
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    
        @Inject permissionHelper permissionHelper;
        @Inject MbAppFeature mpAppFeature;
        @Inject SharedPref sharedPref;
        @Inject ViewMvcFactory viewMvcFactory;
    
    
    @SuppressLint({"ResourceType", "SuspiciousIndentation"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getInjector().inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    
        scanModeNumber = sharedPref.read("scanModeNumber",0);
        isFirstRun = sharedPref.read("isFirstRun", true);

}

Base Activity in kotlin code
    open class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private val appCompositionRoot get() = (application as CustomApplication).appComponent
    
        val activityComponent by lazy {
            DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(ActivityModule(this, appCompositionRoot))
                .build()
        }
    
        private val controllerComponent by lazy {
            DaggerControllerComponent.builder()
                .controllerModule(ControllerModule(activityComponent))
                .build()
        }
    
    
        public val injector get() = controllerComponent
    }

Components in kotlin code
@Component(modules = [ControllerModule::class])
interface ControllerComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

}

@Module
class  ControllerModule
    (private val activityComponent: ActivityComponent)

{
    @Provides
    fun activity() = activityComponent.activity()

    @Provides
    fun layoutInflater()
            = activityComponent.layoutInflater()

    @Provides
    fun sharedPref() = activityComponent.sharedPref()

Error logs
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Integer SharedPref.read(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
at (MainActivity.java:147)
I can see in Dagger Controller Component that injection methods are empty, any suggestion how to solve this:
   @Override
    public void inject(ReadIDActivity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(ResultsIDActivity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(CertificateHandling activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(MainActivity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(LaunchCheckFragment LaunchCheckFragment) {
    }   

Note: Components have been created but injection is not possible
Gradle Version 8.4
Gradle plugin 8.3.1
Java version 17
SOLVED: Update Gradle, update Kotlin, Update the Android Studio   Android Studio Jellyfish, change the activity classes to the same package for dependency modules
activity_version = "1.9.0"
kotlin_version ='1.9.23'
agp_version = '8.4'
dagger_version = '2.51.1'  
 
gradle-8.6-bin.zip     

                            


To enable members injection in your activity, annotate your class with @AndroidEntryPoint
Refer https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point.html

I am trying to use dagger2 separately from hilt, but it doesn't seem to work on newer versions of gradle and dagger, i will try to implement hilt instead
